# Trying to get right combination of Leaflet libraries

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I've inherited a project which was using an ancient version of Leaflet and some associated libraries, and have now managed to add the Google Mutant to it. It used to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.1/leaflet.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/leaflet.draw.0.2.1/leaflet.draw.css" />
```

And

```
<script src="assets/vendor/leaflet.draw.0.2.1/leaflet.draw.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, I've upgraded a few things to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/assets/vendor/leaflet.draw.0.2.3/dist/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/assets/vendor/leaflet.label/leaflet.label.css"/>
```

And

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=BlahBlahBlahCrazyWordsMoustache"></script>
<script src="~/assets/vendor/leaflet.1.6.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/vendor/leaflet.label/leaflet.label.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/vendor/leaflet.draw.0.2.3/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/vendor/leaflet.googleMutant/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js"></script>
```

This is all fine and dandy for the most part - the Google imagery is loading how I want it.

However, there are buttons present that add polygons and polylines, seemingly to a GeoJSON layer, and measure them, as well as functionality to edit and delete them. Now that functionality is seriously compromised - the label/popup which used to appear on mouseover is gone, only the first shape will edit, and nothing will delete. I do get an error message, which is:

```
> Uncaught Error: The provided object is not a Layer. 
> at i.addLayer (leaflet.js:5) 
> at i.showLabel (leaflet.label.js:9)
> at i._showLabel (leaflet.label.js:9)
> at i.fire (leaflet.js:5)
> at i._fireDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
> at i._handleDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
> at HTMLDivElement.s (leaflet.js:5) 
> addLayer @ leaflet.js:5
> showLabel @ leaflet.label.js:9
> _showLabel @ leaflet.label.js:9
> fire @ leaflet.js:5
> _fireDOMEvent @ leaflet.js:5
> _handleDOMEvent @ leaflet.js:5
> s @ leaflet.js:5
```

Comment: Problem is obviously with `Leaflet.label` plugin. Try if demo http://leaflet.github.com/Leaflet.label/ works with latest version of Leaflet.

Comment: Tested. `Leaflet.label` plugin does not work with Leaflet 1.6.

Comment: @TomazicM - thanks, have removed that as the label functioning is now part of the core leaflet. With a bit of jiggery-pokery it seems to be working, though it's caused a few other little problems I'm slowly working through.